# Linux: How to combine multiple FLAC audio files into 1 file, with differing sample rates, but not changing pitch

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, sox

I've looked everywhere to try to combine a bunch of FLAC files with differing sample rates into 1 file. What I've tried so far is:

ffmpeg concat with a wildcard:

`ffmpeg -f concat -i <( for f in *.flac; do echo "file '$(pwd)/$f'"; done ) -safe 0 output.flac`

I get for every filename, (even if I change pwd to './' for relative):

`ffmpeg unsafe filename`

Regardless of the file's filename.

I've tried sox:

`sox *.flac output.flac`

Which leads to:

`sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same sample-rate`

I've even tried combining the two:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

for i in *.flac *.ogg *.mp3
do
  ffmpeg -i "$i" "$i.wav"

done

sox *.wav combined.wav
```

Same error as above.

Anyone have any tips? I'm sure that in some Windows program you can drag in 5 differing sound files and combine them with ease. Is there not a simple way to do this on linux cmdline?

Comment: `-safe 0` should come before `-i`

Comment: Can you make that an answer and I will accept? For reference, the command I ended up using is: `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <( for f in *.flac; do echo "file '$(pwd)/$f'"; done ) output.flac`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`safe 0` is a private option for the concat demuxer, so it has to appear before the input i.e. `-f concat -safe 0 -i ...`